# Do you always have to differentiate with respect to something? When is the derivative of $e^{3x}=3e^{3x}$ and not $3e^{3x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The idea of a derivative, a rate of change, doesn't make sense without being with respect to something. But if you can't take a derivative with respect to nothing, then when can you get the derivative of $e^{3x}$ as being $3e^{3x}dx$ ? That would be implicit differentiation, but does implicit differentiation mean that you aren't taking the derivative with respect to anything?

Comment: For this question to make sense, you must first explain what you mean by the expression “3x^{3x}\,dx”.

Comment: When is it this and not that? If $f(x)=e^{3x}$ then the derivative _is_ $f'(x)=3e^{3x}$; the question of "when" it's something else is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

In implicit differentiation you *are* taking the derivative with respect to something. As an example, say you wanted to differentiate with respect to $x$:
$$x^2y^2=3x+1$$
Note that $y$ is a function of $x$; we can show this more explicitly by writing $x^2\cdot y^2(x)=3x+1$. Now when we take the derivative, we use the chain rule (and product rule) to find this derivative:
$$2x\cdot y^2+2x^2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=3$$
When we differentiate $y(x)$, by the chain rule, we must also multiply by its derivative. We have no weird $dx$ popping up when we do implicit differentiation this way.

To see why we can't differentiate with respect to no variable, recall the definition of the derivative:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Think about what this limit is when we're not taking the derivative with respect to any variable. What does it mean? If you can't think of a satisfactory answer, that's fine, because neither can I.

Answer (score 0):

A function $x\mapsto f(x)$ has its single real independent variable, denoted by $x$ here. This $x$ is a "dummy variable" insofar, as the same function $f$ could also be presented as $t\mapsto f(t)$. The derivative of $f$ is defined by
$$f'(x):=\lim_{h\to0}{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}$$
(of course you knew this), and the value $f'(p)$ is well defined for any given value $p$, independently of the working name given to the independent variable of $f$. It follows that $f'$ is a well defined function.

For the special function $f(x):=e^{3x}$ standard limit procedures give $f'(x)=3e^{3x}$, but $f'(t)=3e^{3t}$ is correct as well.